# How to show deployed image tags in kubernetes cluster via http

Tags: kubernetes

Looking for some ideas on how to expose an http endpoint from kubernetes cluster that shows the docker images tag for each service that is live and up-to-date as services are updated with newer tags.

Example something like this: `GET endpoint.com/api/metadata`

```
{
   "foo-service": "registry.com/foo-service:1.0.1",
   "bar-service": "registry.com/bar-service:2.0.1"
}
```

when `foo-service` is deployed with a new tag `registry.com/foo-service:1.0.2`, I want the endpoint to reflect that change.

I can't just store the values as environment variables as it is not guaranteed the service that exposes that endpoint will be updated on each deploy.

Some previous I had but does not seem clean:

- Update an external file in s3 to keep track of image tags on each deployment, and cache/load data on each request to endpoint.
- Update a key in Redis within the cluster and read from that.

Comment: That sounds like something where you could use the [Kubernetes API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/) as an authoritative source for the data.

Comment: @DavidMaze That is a great suggestion! I was not aware you could access this api from within the cluster. Thanks!

Comment: @MoXue  If your  issue is solved , can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @SaiChandraGadde sure will do.

Answer (score 1):

Folowing on @DavidMaze's suggestion. I ended up using the Kubernetes API to display a formatted version of the deployed services via an rest api endpoint.

Steps:

- Attach a role with relevant permissions to a service account.

```
# This creates a service role that can be attached to
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: service-role
  namespace: dev
rules:
  - verbs:
      - list
    apiGroups:
      - apps
    resources:
      - deployments
```

- Use one of the available kubernetes api libraries to connect to the kubernetes api from within the cluster, Java in my case. And retrieve the deployment list.

```
implementation io.kubernetes:client-java:15.0.1
```

- Output the result of the kubernetes api call and expose a cached version of it through an endpoint (Java snippet)

```
public Map<String, String> getDeployedServiceVersions() { 
            ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
            Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

            AppsV1Api api = new AppsV1Api();
            V1DeploymentList v1DeploymentList = api.listNamespacedDeployment(releaseNamespace, null, false, null, null, null, null, null, null, 10, false);
            # Helper method to map deployments to result
            return getServiceVersions(v1DeploymentList);
}
```